# Посоветуйте 3D библиотеку для Android разработки

Tags: android, java, 3d

Необходима библиотека для вывода 3d графика функции. Или выводила 3d график в  2d плоскость с выделением уровней цветом. Библиотека на Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вывода графиков активно используется [Achartengine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

Легко кастомизируется, имеет множество различных графиков.
Про 3d-графики возможно подскажут [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517624/3d-charts-libraries-in-android)

Есть еще такая либа - [charts4j](https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/)